# Allow certain OUTBOUND connection

Tags: linux, iptables

I try to connect to a remote host over ssh (139.162.206.137) but iptables block the connection.
This is my actual iptables configuration

```
[root@SRV1 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set IPs_countries src
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set IPs_blacklist src
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  81.51.151.22.dyn.user.ono.com  anywhere             tcp dpt:6556
ACCEPT     tcp  --  81.51.151.22.dyn.user.ono.com  anywhere             tcp dpt:12800
ACCEPT     tcp  --  81.51.151.22.dyn.user.ono.com  anywhere             tcp dpt:12801
ACCEPT     icmp --  81.51.151.22.dyn.user.ono.com  anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

There aren't any block policy
If I stop iptables service I can connect correctly. What exactly happend with my outbound connection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall is not blocking the outbound connection (The OUTPUT table has no rules, and has a default allow).

The problem is likely that the return packets from the server are being dropped - ie it is a problem with the INPUT table.

My guess is that one of the first 2 rules are preventing the ssh connection from working.   They should come AFTER the "state RELATED,ESTABLISHED" rule, so you should re-order your rules with those blocks at the end.

An alternative would be a specific exception for the machine you are trying to SSH into, like

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
```

to accept any traffic from that host or

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s X.X.X.X -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

To limit it to SSH traffic from that IP.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a rule to allow packet from ssh remote server to your local machine.

```
sudo iptables -A  INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22  -j ACCEPT
```

If it doesn't work after adding rule. You can try to change the position by inserting the rule as the first one

```
sudo iptables -I  INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22  -j ACCEPT
```